# Can I access a Mac Numbers (.num) document from within R?

Tags: r, macos, iwork, apple-numbers

I know I can use the RODBC library for accessing excel (.xls) docs from within Windows, but is there something similar for the Numbers program that come with iWorks?   If not, what other solutions are there for easily editing a spreadsheet (like a lookup table) and accessing it within R?  I know there the is an internal R editor, but I don't like it very much.

Comment: Not sure, but you might have to export the Numbers file to XLS first, but that opens up other compatibility issues. Best bet is to read from a simple CSV file, if you can.

Comment: yeah, that's what I'm doing at the moment, I just hate editing the CSV file as if I include tabs to separate the data to make it easy to read, then these tabs are then included with the variables when I import.

Comment: I usually re-import CSV files into my spreadsheet application and then re-save as CSV when I have to edit.  Unless the edits are fairly minor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative option you could consider is using Google spreadsheets.  You can then access the data from either [RGoogleDocs](http://www.omegahat.org/RGoogleDocs/) or [RGoogleData](http://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/rgoogledata/).