# R export to .numbers spreadsheet

Tags: r, macos, export

Is there any package/function that will let me to directly output R data frames to **.numbers** spreadsheet.

I want to bypass exporting to CSV/Excel from R before taking the output to numbers spreadsheet.

Comment: As of this question at 2010, it didn't seem like there was any direct linkage between Numbers and R - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494676/can-i-access-a-mac-numbers-num-document-from-within-r

Comment: No evidence of searching on your part. Wasn't too hard too find this" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19571787/reverse-engineering-iwork-13-formats

Comment: @BondedDust - I know what I'm doing in R, and I wouldn't know where to even start with that information to be able to export a file.

Comment: @thelatemail:  I apologize if you thought I was criticising your helpful response. I meant for it to be directed to Karthik.